# How to resolve CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password in Core PHP?

Tags: php, security

In a php page, $_REQUEST['password'] is directly getting the value and passing this to a function. However, in that line Use of Hard-coded Password showing up in Veracode scan. Can anyone suggest a solution how to solve this?

Comment: Remove the password. Don't hardcode real password into code.

Comment: Maybe not what [CWE-259: Use of Hard-coded Password](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/259.html) had in mind, but you're seemingly accepting passwords as URL parameter. Even if using HTTPS, that's a significant risk. What's your exact use case?

Comment: Here scenario is getting password like $_REQUEST and passing to ldap_bind. Error is populating in that line. So how we can remove password from code in core php.

Comment: But why does it need to support passwords in URL? Do you need to share access links? Does it integrate with some other platform that doesn't support POST?

Comment: If PHP is just receiving inbound data and passing it to another system, then there isn't a hard-coded password in PHP.  However, as a separate issue, if you're putting the password as a URL parameter, that is a security risk, as others have pointed out.  It would be better to do this via POST instead

Answer (score 0):

You should encrypt  or hash the password before assignee to the variable
I recommend you to do some encryption is more secure and is more correct
and should do some sanitization of the password..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).